# Apache proxy forward wildcard subdomain to tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat7, mod-proxy, virtual-hosts

How do I setup the virtual host to forward the subdomin part to my tomcat.

I know * does not work....but how do I achieve something as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ServerName *.example.com
 ProxyPass /app1 *.localhost:8080/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well that was a stupid question, the

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
```

by itself will preserve the original request so I don't have to forward the subdomain.

just the below will work..

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ServerName *.example.com
 ProxyPass /app1 http://localhost:8080/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

and my code actually sees http://subdomain.example.com/app1

Answer (score 0):

Use one specific servername (perhaps "dummy"), then use the wildcard in a
`ServerAlias` statement:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ServerName dummy.example.com
 ServerAlias *.example.com
 ProxyPass /app1 *.localhost:8080/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: ProxyPass must be absolute